# JMeter Threads, Ramp-up and Loop what the correct usage?

Tags: jmeter

I am under the impression that I use the 3 settings; Threads, Ramp-up and Loop, to simulate X (Threads) amount of users/thread over Y (Ramp-up) seconds and do these for Z (Loop) amount of times. For example I want 10 users every 1 second for 1 hour which equates to 10 Threads, 1 Second Ramp-up and 3600 Loops.

But :)

Others seems to be using it differently ... as in if they want the same as above they would set Threads to 36000, Ramp-up to 3600 seconds and Loop to 1.

I tend to think the first approach is correct based on #a it reads better :) and #b why would you have a setting based in seconds to indicate the length of your test

Can anyone give me a definitive answer or are both options plausible?

Comment: So there should only be 10 users performing the action at any one time? Or does the amount of users performing the action increase over the course of test (10 in second#1, 20 in second#2...)

Comment: The documentation states that if you want 5 threads and a ramp-up time of 5 seconds then it will spread the creation and execution of the threads over the Ramp-up time of 5 seconds, so in that case 1 per second.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly 36000 threads in the second example seems very high! http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/HowManyThreads reports people using 1000. So the 2nd scenario may not even work.

The two scenarios you describe are not exactly the same, and I'm not sure if either are exactly what you want.

In the first the 10 Threads plus 1 second Ramp-up means all 10 Threads will be in use after 1 second. The 10 Threads will then do their actions in parallel 3600 times. You have not mentioned anything that will mean the test will take 1 hour, it will take as long as it takes to loop through 3600 times. To make it take an hour (assuming the actions don't take longer than 1 second) you would need something like a Constant Throughput Timer within your loop which control the speed of the loop so that it takes an hour.

In the second, 10 threads would be created in `second #1` and start doing their loop, another 10 in the `second#2`, etc, all the way up to 1 hour (`second#3600`). If the actions take longer than one second, then you would have more than 10 threads running in any one second.

The first approach is much clearer. The 2nd one is a misuse of the Ramp-Up; it's not being used to provide a ramp-up to 360000 threads, but to try and schedule 10 threads to run at once.

Comment: With regards to the comment "Firstly 36000 threads in the second example seems very high!" ... this (According to the documentation) means that Jmeter will divide the 36000 threads by the Ramp-up of 3600 which equates to 10 threads per 1 second ... which is my point, why would someone want do to it that way rather than using the 'Loop' variable to compound the simple task of 10 threads per 1 second.

Comment: With regards to the comment "You have not mentioned anything that will mean the test will take 1 hour, it will take as long as it takes to loop through 3600 times" ... correct, but 'roughly' if jmeter fires of 10 threads every 1 second (and completes these within the second) 3600 times then 3600 x 1 sec = 1 hr.

Comment: "The first approach is much clearer." ... I agree but I need to provide a good argument for this :)

Comment: 1) A ramp-up of 36000 implies the test will ramp-up to 36000 threads, which it won't, so the test is misleading to anyone maintaining it later 2) there is no guarantee that only 10 threads will be running at any one time in the 2nd case, it could 10, 20, 30...

Comment: "there is no guarantee that only 10 threads will be running at any one time in the 2nd case" ... there is no guarantee in either case because like you said each batch of threads may take longer than the ramp-up to complete so you may then have more threads running than indicated by the 'thread' setting.

Comment: "A ramp-up of 36000 implies the test will ramp-up to 36000 thread" ... I might not think this based on the fact that the 'ramp-up' setting indicates the term 'Seconds' which leads me to think of duration, which might be the reason why people use it; incorrectly, to indicate how long to run the test for.

Comment: In the first case, there can not be more than 10 thread running, because you only have 10 threads configured. Each thread is running a loop, if an action takes longer than 1 second, the next iteration of that thread's loop won't start and you won't have > 10 threads running.

Comment: Is that correct? ... I was under the impression that X amount of Threads will get create over the duration of every Ramp-up seconds, for every Loop 'regardless' of whether any of them have finished or not ... maybe I missed this in the documentation.